# I'm trying to set up a new SharePoint production server and getting an error creating an Open XML 2.5 document

Tags: vb.net, openxml

I have a SharePoint application written in Visual Basic that works fine and creates Word Documents using Open XML 2.5 on my development machine. We recently set up a new Production server and I published the .wsp file and deployed it on the new server. The application all works fine except the code that generates reports in Word format. It fails on the following line of code.

***Dim wpd As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(MemStream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, True)***

This is what the code looks like in the function that is failing.

```
''' \<summary\>
''' 
''' \</summary\>
''' \<param name="MemStream"\>\</param\>
''' \<returns\>\</returns\>
Public Function WPDCreateFromStream(MemStream As MemoryStream) As WordprocessingDocument
   Try
      Dim wpd As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(MemStream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, True)
      Dim MainPart As MainDocumentPart = wpd.AddMainDocumentPart()
      MainPart.Document = New Document()
      Dim DocBody As New Body()
      Return wpd
   Catch ex As Exception
      WriteErrorToEventLog("OpenXML", "WPDCreateFromStream", "", ex)
      Return Nothing
   End Try
End Function
```

Here is the exception detail I get when trying to make the WordProcessingDocument.Create call above.

ERROR: Source: OpenXML Routine: WPDCreateFromStream User:

Message: The type initializer for 'MS.Utility.EventTrace' threw an exception.

StackTrace:    at MS.Utility.EventTrace.EasyTraceEvent(Keyword keywords, Event eventID)
at System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(Stream stream, FileMode packageMode, FileAccess packageAccess, Boolean streaming)
at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.CreateCore(Stream stream)
at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument.Create(Stream stream, WordprocessingDocumentType type, Boolean autoSave)
at FIS.SP.PSTARProjectTracker.PSTAR.Core.BusinessLogic.OpenXML.WPDCreateFromStream(MemoryStream MemStream)

Source: WindowsBase

Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal

InnerException: System.Security.SecurityException: Requested registry access is not allowed.
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowSecurityException(ExceptionResource resource)
at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String name, Boolean writable)
at Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(String keyName, String valueName, Object defaultValue)
at MS.Utility.EventTrace.IsClassicETWRegistryEnabled()
at MS.Utility.EventTrace..cctor()
The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
MyComputer

ToString: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MS.Utility.EventTrace' threw an exception. ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Requested registry access is not allowed.
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowSecurityException(ExceptionResource resource)
at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String name, Boolean writable)
at Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(String keyName, String valueName, Object defaultValue)
at MS.Utility.EventTrace.IsClassicETWRegistryEnabled()
at MS.Utility.EventTrace..cctor()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at MS.Utility.EventTrace.EasyTraceEvent(Keyword keywords, Event eventID)
at System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(Stream stream, FileMode packageMode, FileAccess packageAccess, Boolean streaming)
at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.CreateCore(Stream stream)
at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument.Create(Stream stream, WordprocessingDocumentType type, Boolean autoSave)
at FIS.SP.PSTARProjectTracker.PSTAR.Core.BusinessLogic.OpenXML.WPDCreateFromStream(MemoryStream MemStream)

TargetSite: Void EasyTraceEvent(Keyword, Event)

I know this is not an issue with the code as the same code works in development. I assume it has to do with  permissions, or getting the DocumentFormat.OpenXML.dll installed / registered correctly on the new server, but I've had no luck searching for a solution.

I tried installing OpenXML and the Productivity tool on the server. The productivity tool works and can open a word document, but the Application has the same issue.

If anyone has run into this and can point me to a solution, I would appreciate it.

---

The MemoryStream is created and passed in to be used by this function. The WordProcessingDocument is returned to the calling function. I could explicitly call ByVal, but in this case it would not change anything.

I am creating a new document, that is why it is coded using WordProcessingDocument.Create

Remember, this code all functions perfectly on the development SharePoint server. It has been used heavily for about a year. I'm just trying to get this to work on a new production server we recently stood up. I have to believe this is related to some permission issue, or a component that is not installed or registered correctly. For Open XML, I believe there is just the one DLL (DocumentFormat.OpenXML.DLL) and it does not register. It is on the server from installing the .wsp package. I also tried installing Open XML 2.5 on the server along with the productivity tool and they all work fine.

The more I think about it, it just feels like a permission issue.

Comment: According to [Passing Arguments by Value and by Reference (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/passing-arguments-by-value-and-by-reference): _In Visual Basic, you can pass an argument to a procedure by value or by reference...The default in Visual Basic is to pass arguments by value_.  Are you are intending to pass in a document as a `MemoryStream`?

Comment: It seems that perhaps you should be using  [WordprocessingDocument.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.wordprocessingdocument.open?view=openxml-2.8.1) rather than [WordprocessingDocument.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.wordprocessingdocument.create?view=openxml-2.8.1#documentformat-openxml-packaging-wordprocessingdocument-create(system-io-stream-documentformat-openxml-wordprocessingdocumenttype-system-boolean))

Comment: The following may be of interest: ["Requested registry access is not allowed" error is create spreadsheet from restricted account (IIS etc.)](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues/942)

Comment: That post looks promising, but it does not have a solution. It does lend credibility that it is a permission issue, but I do not know what permission needs to change.

Comment: OK, I found and addressed this issue. The root cause was a permission issue. The following registry key needed to have permissions added for "Everyone" set to Read access. [HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-527237240-2000478354-839522115-1119710\Software\Microsoft\Avalon.Graphics]. Once that permission was added, Open XML worked flawlessly. Still not sure why it was needed, but it solved my problem. Thanks to those that tried to assist!